# How to remove trailing whitespace in mail signature

Tags: message-mode

I'm trying to get rid of the auto-inserted trailing whitespace in `message-mode` signature. I have tried the advice below.

```el
(defadvice message-insert-signature (around +amos*message-insert-signature activate)
  (let ((old-insert (symbol-function 'insert)))
    (flet ((insert (str) (eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x)) (funcall old-insert (string-trim-right str))))
      ad-do-it)))
```

But it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Where does the trailing whitespace appear? After the double hyphen `--` separator? Have you configured `message-mode` to insert a signature at all? If so, where does it get populated from? A string, file or elsewhere? It may help if you provide a sample mail transcript (e.g. an expected vs actual text comparison) to indicate which whitespace you are trying to eliminate.

Comment: Yep, after the double hyphen -- separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the last two paragraphs of [`(message) Insertion Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/message/Insertion-Variables.html) and [this `comp.mail.headers` post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.mail.headers/mwMXPyUaDoc/ZQjPL5lxZsoJ) by the package's author:

```
Quoth RFC1036bis:

    If  a  poster or posting agent does append a signature to an
    article, the signature SHOULD be preceded with  a  delimiter
    line  containing  (only)  two hyphens (ASCII 45) followed by
    one blank (ASCII  32).

Note that this isn't a standard in any formal sense, and RFC1036 is a
Usenet news thing.  However, it has been the done thing since, well,
forever.  It works.
```

the trailing space is considered conventional, if not a bit outdated, netiquette. In more practical terms, however, `message-mode` feels quite strongly about enforcing this convention in the messages it helps you compose by hard-coding the trailing space in at least a couple of places. I believe it is possible to work around these, but minor unforeseen complications are always possible:

```el
(defun my-message-trim-signature ()
  "Delete trailing space of `message-mode' signature."
  (let ((marker (point-marker)))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "^-- $" nil t)
      (delete-char -1))
    (goto-char marker)))

(add-hook 'message-setup-hook #'my-message-trim-signature)

;; Teach paragraph motion commands about our signature
(defun my-message-fix-paragraphs ()
  "Adapt paragraph variables to `my-message-trim-signature'."
  (setq paragraph-start (concat "--$\\|" paragraph-start))
  (setq paragraph-separate paragraph-start))

(add-hook 'message-mode-hook #'my-message-fix-paragraphs)

;; "Loosen" regexp for `message-goto-signature' et al. to work
(setq message-signature-separator "^-- *$")
```